# How to determine building types and add them to the attribute table

Tags: attribute-table, query

I have a city in which the buildings are defined as polygons. I have determined the area based on these polygons, however I would also like to determine the building type (i.e. terraced, semi-detached or detached building) and add this to the attribute table (i.e. link the building type to the respective building ID). Can I also do this based on the polygons?

I assume it would be possible based on a spatial analysis/query, however I just can not find a tool or a way to do this. As there are a huge amount of buildings it would take a lot of time to visually check the building type and adding this manually in the attribute table.

Could somebody help me out?

Comment: What software are you using?

Comment: If the buildings haven't been classified with this information in the attribute table already, this is probably going to be absurdly difficult to offer any guidance without knowing your personal knowledge base and other available information and data.  The simplest method for classifying the buildings you have based on the information you've provided would be to set size thresholds for different types. That it, smaller than 500 square feet is an "outbuilding/shed", 500-1000 sqft is a "garage", 1000-3000sqft is a "residential house", 3000+ is "commercial", etc. something like that.

Comment: Thank you for your answers. Here is more information:
- I'm using the ArcMap software which I've just started using. So I'm a beginner.
- I have a shapefile in which every building is defined as a polygon and has its own reference number ("Building ID"). I also have some other informatin e.g. building year, but I think that's not relevant for you.
- Based on the generated map I can visually see which buildings are e.g. terraced or detached, however as I have a lot of buildings (10.000 +) it's not possible to determine the building type for each building manually.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  As a new user be sure to take the [Tour] to learn about the site and its protocols.  Please use the [edit] button beneath your question to revise it with any requested information.